# Shortening a ternary with null coalesce

Tags: javascript

Is it correct that you can shorten a ternary operator with a `??` if it is checking for itself?  I have the data below:

```
function myFunct(isEnabled) {
     this.doOtherFunc({ 
         isEnabled: isEnabled ? isEnabled : true,
     })
}
```

can I rewrite it as follows?  If `isEnabled` exists, give the `true/false` value of it -- otherwise, use `true`

```
function myFunct(isEnabled) {
     this.doOtherFunc({ 
         isEnabled: isEnabled ?? true,
     })
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that approach?

Comment: Isn't it even shorter as `isEnabled: true`? Because that seems to be the logic here.

Comment: Presumably in your original you mean `typeof(isEnabled) == 'undefined' ? true : isEnabled`

Comment: @VLAZ it's a toggle sometimes so  `isEnabled` can come in as `false` and that needs to be logged.  Some places where its not used as a toggle, `myFunc` is called without the argument

Comment: @joynerj9j `isEnabled ? isEnabled : true` means that if `isEnabled` is *any falsy value* then `true` would be used. And if it's any truthy value, the truthy value would be used. Therefore `isEnabled ?? true` is not at all equivalent, as the outcome differs for `isEnabled = false`.

Comment: thanks @vlaz , so it sounds like if I want to use the true/false value of `isEnabled` if it exists, I can use the null coalesce.  I tried a test function:  `function foo(boolVal) { console.log(boolVal ?? 'none') }`. If I run `foo()` and pass in a `true` or `false`, it logs that.  If I run `foo` without an arg, it logs `none`

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to express. `isEnabled ? isEnabled : true` is equivalent to `isEnabled || true`. Which replaces **all falsy values** like `null` or `false`, ... with `true` and keeps all truthy values, like `true` or `[]` or `"false"`. The null coalescing operator only replaces `null`/`undefined` values and keeps everything else. Another alternative would be to use a default value for your function argument: `function myFunct(isEnabled = true) {` to express your intention.

Comment: @Thomas I am trying to pass in `isEnabled` if it exists, regardless of whether it is `true` or `false` .  If it doesnt exist, then default to `true`

Comment: You should clarify for yourself and be precise what you mean with `If it doesnt exist`. `typeof arg === "undefined"`, `arguments.length > 0` and on objects `typeof obj[key] !== "undefined"` vs `key in obj` vs `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` are in a way all different definitions on what it means for a value to exist, because depending on how you test this "existance" you get different results. And all these examples only deal with `undefined`, not with `null` or stuff like falsy or invalid values.

Answer (score 1):

You could take [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

```
function myFunct(isEnabled = true) {
    this.doOtherFunc({ isEnabled });
}
```